# How can I over add custom headers to socket.io ' s response with express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to override CORS policy with:-

```
app.use('/\*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, PUT")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    next()
})
```

But while the socket.io framework returns its client-side JavaScript to the browsers, the app.use('/*') event has no effect on its response.

So what should I do to add custom headers such as "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the client-side script of socket.io in order to use it?

As my server using Socket.io is on a different server with a different IP address.

And I have to used the js as below in the browser

```
import io from 'http://diffentdomainname.com/socket.io/socket.io.js'; //this is where I get cors error
```

Although my app.use() code works well if I embed the JS inside HTML with

```
<script src="http://diffentdomainname.com/socket.io/socket.io.js">
```

Comment: Are you *just* trying to modify the ``Access-Control-Allow-Origin`` header? Or are you also trying to modify the other CORS headers?

Comment: Well, most importantly the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header when the server responds to the path `/socket.io/socket.io.js` (which is the default path for client-side JavaScript Code in Socket.io Framework).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`io.origins();`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-origins-value), which sets the origins that could connect to the `socket.io` server and request the client script. By default, this allows all origins, so you shouldn't even be getting a CORS error.

To use it, just supply the origins you want to allow, as strings, in an array:

```js
// Code...
// Specify the origins
io.origins(["http://thisdomain.com", "http://thatdomain.com"]);
// Or, use a custom function
io.origins((origin, callback) => {
  // Check the origin and stuff.
});
```

Comment: Yes I know that default Origin is `*` default, And I have never encountered CORS error as long as I was using it like `<script src="http://host/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, I encountered this problem when I used it as `import io from 'http://host/socket.io/socket.io.js';`